# Django REST API: run operations after put request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to find a clean way to process some task after successfully completes the PUT request for REST API. I am using post_update() function but its never being called. Here is my code

```
class portfolio_crud(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = user_ticker_portfolio_serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return user_ticker_portfolio.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("got the put request to update portfolio")
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post_update(self, serializer):
        print("got the post save call") #never executed
```

Comment: Did you try some *Asynchronous* task tools like **[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)**?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to do, but I usually use [django's post_save hook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save) as opposed to something on the viewset or serializer.  Something like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=YourPortolioClass)
def portfolio_post_save(sender, created, instance, raw, **kwargs):
    """ We need to do something after updating a portfolio
    """
    if created or raw:
        return

    # do your update stuff here.
```

Comment: The problem with the solution is, this signal will execute ***whenever a `save()` occur in the corresponding model***, But the OP asks about something like a signal which executes after a specific REST action

Comment: thanks for the update! what is the purpose of "perform_update(self, serializer)" function. I was reading from the django doc... 
"These override points are also particularly useful for adding behavior that occurs before or after saving an object, such as emailing a confirmation, or logging the update."

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.save()
    send_email_confirmation(user=self.request.user, modified=instance)

I just dont know how to use the above hook.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be much help to you (but I hope so) - I just use multithreading and create another thread before returning.

I don't see anything calling that function... but I am curious

Comment: Thanks... I think its a little patchy solution in my case

Comment: Another option would be to use Celery (which I don't like)